# Best practice for dockerizing a springboot app in a CICD pipeline

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, cicd

**Context**: I'm able to dockerize and run my Springboot app *locally* just fine with the below, following the most common recommendations of using a generated jar file to run the app via Docker.

**Question**: Since it's bad practice to push the jar file to the repo as it's going to potentially contain secrets from the local application.yml files, and the docker file depends on the jar file, how can I have my app be dockerized not just locally but on the cloud in anywhich cicd pipeline? Would my next step be modifying the dockerfile to copy over the project directory, and handle generating the jar file itself? Or should I not be using a jar at all and copying over the directory and using a CMD [Some Spring Run command)]

DockerFile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17
ADD target/xyz.jar xyz.jar

ENV RESTFUL_PORT 8080
ENV PORT_POSTGRES 5432
EXPOSE $RESTFUL_PORT
EXPOSE $PORT_POSTGRES

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","/xyz.jar"]
```

The pom.xml plugin which generates the jar file:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

#### Docker Steps

1. Build the Jar:
   `mvn clean install`
2. Build the Image:
   `docker build -t xyz -f Dockerfile`
3. Run the Image:
   `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev" xyz`

Comment: This question is opinion based (as in, it depends) But I also get the impression that you didn't do the basic research. https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje I've done research, else how would I have gotten to the point of atleast being able to run locally. Thanks for the link, however those docs still have the docker file depending on a jar file and doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @TrollBearPig would you mind explaining more thoroughly what exactly you would like to avoid?

Comment: Btw, as indicated by the above link, you don't need a Dockerfile - _Spring Boot supports building a container from Maven or Gradle by using its own build plugin._ More importantly, the Maven image isn't meant to be used for runtime containers

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks I know Spring can build the image itself. My pipeline however depends on the DockerFile to build the image, and does not support a Registry I could push an image directly into. I am trying to remove the dependency of the Dockerfile from the Jar file as the Jar will have sensitive data and cannot be pushed up to Git. DockerFile can still use a jar, but would have to build it itself on the fly.

Comment: JAR files are not pushed to Git. Only java source files are. If you have sensitive secrets, such as database credentials, then those will also be readable inside of Docker images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FROM maven:3.8-openjdk-17-slim AS build
WORKDIR /workspace/app

COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src

RUN mvn -f /workspace/app/pom.xml install
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

FROM openjdk:17-oracle
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/target/dependency
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.demo.DemoServiceApplication"]
```

Got it working with this, only needing to change the last line.

Docker Command:

- docker build -t demo -f Dockerfile .
- docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=develop" demo:latest

This results in a DockerFile that is not dependent on an external jar file and can be run in isolation against a repo for a cicd pipeline.

**Source**: [Toptal - Multi-Stage Build](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker)

Comment: This Dockerfile does not hide your secrets in local properties files. I still see them under **app** folder. The source you shared is related with decreasing build times using cached layers.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dockerfile` can be like this:

```
# Build Stage
FROM maven:3.8-openjdk-17-slim AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

# Execution Stage
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/demo-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/demo.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/demo.jar"]
```

To build docker image

```
$ docker build -t demo-app:1.0 .
```

Run docker image

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 demo-app:1.0
```

Simple build part of `pom.xml` will work

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Did not compile for me, but thanks ! It helped me get in the right direction.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Thank you, if you need to supply custom settings.xml then it will be `mvn -s settings.xml clean install`